# How to click Activex Install button of IE browser using Selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-9

I am working with Selenium webdriver using java for automating a project. The web application shows an activex plugin to be installed alert once we login using Internet Explorer 9. I need to click the install button of this activex alert using Selenium web driver. Can someone please provide me a solution for this.

The alert message will be like "Internet explorer blocked this website from installing an Activex control" message with a Install button.

Thank you,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

You cannot click on that button with `Selenium-Webdriver` as that button is part of the browser and not of the page, `Webdriver` can only interact with `HTML elements`.

You will need to use a different tool to handle this button. Other suggestions mentioned on StackOverflow usually involve using the `Robot` class or `Autoit`. Unfortunately, I don't know much about either. I'm sure that with research you will find your answer.